# How to convert a decimal number into string but keeping all the decimal places (including non-significant zeros)

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, tostring

In C# I have a decimal type:

```
decimal? decimalNumber;
```

Supposing that it is not null, how can I convert it into a string while maintaining all the decimal places including non-significant zeros? I want to obtain the same exact decimal number (not truncated, not rounded, etc.) but as a string.

Simply I use below:

```
decimalNumber.ToString();
```

which is the same as doing:

```
decimalNumber.ToString("G");
string.Format("{0:G}", decimalNumber);
```

since `ToString()` by default applies G format internally.

Am I right?

Finally, Is it the same as `decimalNumber.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`? it seems the output is the same.

Comment: `ToString()` uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` by default.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings